# Подскажите что здесь не так? Выдает ошибку

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно сделать страницу каталога handmade товаров. Основные данные в каталоге - это мастера и их товары. необходимо создать единственный массив $data, и придумать его структуру таким образом, чтобы можно было удобно хранить информацию по мастерам и их товарам.

```
$data = [
    "Товары"('Бетон'=>100, 'Герб'=>150, 'Квадрат'=>799)
    "Мастера"('Nick'=>Москва, 'Чебурашка'=>Челябинск, 'Black'=>Казань)
];
```

Comment: На будущее: Во-первых, если уж задаете вопрос, то надо всегда писать, **какую ошибку** вам выдаёт. Тут нет телепатов. А во-вторых, никогда не надо выдумывать синтаксис из головы. Надо посмотреть готовый пример и делать на его основе.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильный синтаксис массива.
Кроме того, строки надо заключать в кавычки.

```php
$data = [
    'Товары' => [
      'Бетон' => 100,
      'Герб' => 150,
      'Квадрат' => 799,
     ],
    'Мастера' => [
      'Nick'=> 'Москва',
      'Чебурашка'=> 'Челябинск',
      'Black' => 'Казань'
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это будет правильным ответом на тест, но у меня был принят такой вариант:

```
$data = [
        'Чебурашка' => ['Челябинск', 'нет', []],
        'Nick' => ['Москва', 'да', ['Бетон' => 100, 'Герб' => 150, ]],
        'Black' => ['Казань', 'нет', ['Квадрат' => 799, ]],
];
```

---

Хотя, именно для хранения и обработки информации, на мой дилетантский взгляд, была бы удобнее следующая конструкция:

```
$data2 = [

    'Мастера' => [
        'Чебурашка' => ['Челябинск', false],
        'Nick' => ['Москва', true],
        'Black' => ['Казань', false],
    ],

    'Товары' => [
        'Бетон' => [100, 'Nick'],
        'Герб' => [150, 'Nick'],
        'Квадрат' => [799, 'Black'],
        ]
];
```

...но её тестирование не захотело принимать...